# Response.Write output in single line

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im trying to output data from gridview in one line inside txt file , but the output is coming in multiple lines

```
Dim str As New StringBuilder()

    For i = 0 To RowNo - 1

        str.Append("EDR,")
        str.Append(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Text)
        str.Append(",")
        str.Append("929110101,")
        str.Append(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Text)
        str.Append(",")
        str.Append("1,")
        str.Append(System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text), Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text)))
        str.Append(",")
        str.Append(System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text), Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text)))
        str.Append(",")
        str.Append(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Text))
        str.Append(",")
        str.Append(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Text)


    Next


    Response.Clear()

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.txt")

    Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1"

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"

    Dim stringWrite As New System.IO.StringWriter()

    Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)

    Response.Write(str.ToString())

    Response.[End]()
```

my output is coming like that

EDR,00000000000000005353291
,929110101,10020108428318
,1,31,31,7397,0

what I need is

EDR,00000000000000005353291,929110101,10020108428318,1,31,31,7397,0

Comment: Not sure but looking at the code, it looks like the data which is coming from the grid contains a newline character in the end. Possibly you can try removing it, and it may work. You can put a break point and check for the value. In case there are new line characters you can replace them with empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace newline character . In VB.NET newline is represented by vbCr,vbLf constants.

`str= str.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sanitizing the string?

```
myString = myString.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"")
```